# Can Ubuntu use multiple devices for downloading?

Tags: internet-connection, ethernet, network-bonding

Let me give an example:

I have one laptop, it is connected to 3 different networks all with access to internet.
One device uses eth0, another uses wlan0 and a third one uses wlan1.

Does Ubuntu knows how to use all connection together to download a file ? is that even possible ?

the point is having a faster data transfer rate.

Comment: You want to bond three different networks together for one single TCP/UDP connection? No, this is not possible in any operating system as this is basic networking preventing you to do this. Imagine that the target machine sees three different IP addresses (3 different hosts). You *can* configure a fail-over in this case, or spread 1/3 of the IP address space over each connection in the routing table.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/53499/how-to-merge-multiple-internet-connections-into-one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for integrating multiple network connections, [ISPUnity](https://github.com/aruntomar/isp_unity) may help you out.

Have a look at [this blog article](http://theforevernoob.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/ispunity/) to get started.

Comment: Good suggestion. It's a rather easy way of setting up an internet connection load balancer. However, this does not speed up a single download.