# I want to run 100 USB 3G in Ubuntu simultaneously?

Tags: usb, 3g

Does anyone here know how to connect 100 USB 3G dongles to a system running Linux and run all those USB simultaneously ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Run all those USB" ? If you want to bond multiple connections together to increase speed, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/53499/how-to-merge-multiple-internet-connections-into-one Or do you want to achieve something else ? But 100 dongles ? That seems a bit.. odd. And _very complicated_. What do you want to achieve, maybe there's a better way to do it than a bunch of 3g dongles.

Comment: I want to make a proxy server using the IP from those USB 3G.